# Java - comparison of positive and negative zeros

Tags: java, floating-point, comparison-operators

Why is Java inconsistent in comparing -0.0 and +0.0?  What is the Java standard method for comparing numbers to account for -0/+0?

I have encountered this particular bugaboo:

```
public class ZeroCompare {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        if ( 0.0 == -0.0 ) {
            System.out.println("== --> same");
        } else {
            System.out.println("== --> different");
        }

        if ( new Double(0.0).equals( -0.0 ) ) {
            System.out.println("equals --> same");
        } else {
            System.out.println("equals --> different");
        }
    }
}
```

It prints the following:

```
== --> same
equals --> different
```

I strongly dislike the fact that how you compare these two values affects the outcome and I'd love for an explanation.

Comment: first the literal inside equals( -0.0 ) is it Float not Double. and second the equals method compares objects and for different literals there are different wrapper objects.

Comment: @amitmahajan It's a double. It would require an `f` or `F` at the end to be a float literal.

Comment: By the way, floating point numbers are never compared for exact equality. They require a small delta value to see if two numbers are close enough to be considered equal (although in this particular case this is a minor issue).

Comment: You are right it defaults to double, but how does it stores the sigh bit without loosing precision.

Comment: @Kayaman: It is perfectly reasonable to compare floating-point numbers for equality.

Comment: @tmyklebu Not generally when given arbitrary floating-point numbers. The precision can cause problems if there isn't a threshold of "equality". The threshold's size depends on the business logic and other such things.

Comment: @Kayaman: I get what you're saying, but for whatever reason people never say "pointers are never dereferenced because some pointers are null" or "you shouldn't add two integers because one might be an index into an array and another might be a copyright year."  There are many cases where testing floating-point equality is the only correct thing to do.  This kind of stupid rule of thumb cannot substitute for thinking about what your program does.  (Put another way, your logic errors are not floating-point math's responsibility.)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This behaviour is [actually documented](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#equals-java.lang.Object-):

> If d1 represents +0.0 while d2 represents -0.0, or vice versa, the equal test has the value false, even though +0.0==-0.0 has the value true. This definition allows hash tables to operate properly.

Comment: Thanks for the link.  When i googled it, I had originally hoped the java doc would be pulled up.  But apparently, Google finds stackoverflow much more popular.

Comment: I don't know if I agree with Java's determination that this "allows hash tables to operate properly"

Imagine I have floating point values (32- or 64-bit ) that I'm using as the key in a hash map (weird, I know. It's an example.)  Assume my code works with floats, but hashes on Floats.  Because of autoboxing, I can index with the float directly.  Outside the hash map, 0.0 and -0.0 would compare the same -- but they would create two different entries in the hash map.  Python goes the other way; since 0.0 and -0.0 are considered "equal", they hash the same.  I think I prefer that.

Answer (score 2):

Java Language Specification: [Numerical Comparison Operators <, <=, >, and >=](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.20.1)

> Positive zero and negative zero are considered equal.

Double.valueOf(+0.0) and Double.valueOf(-0.0) have different bits representation. Double.equals compares bit representation.

Also you can use [Double.compare](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#compare(double,%20double))

Comment: I'm surprised that the Double bit representation of +/- 0.0 are different than the primitive representation.  I'd always assumed it was simply an object wrapper so you could push the primitive into collections.  That said, even if the bit representation of the underlying value was identical to the primitive (which I assume is the case), the "equals" method is not bound in any way shape or form to use the == operator to determine equality.  That's kind of its point.

Comment: Representation is different for primitive type too, but Java lang specification says that operators (> < ...) do not use bit to bit compare.